# Developing and Publishing Custom Django Modules

Tags: python, django

How should I create a Django app for 3rd party use? I've been hacking on something lately and I'd like to put it up on GitHub and let it loose. How should I structure it? Is there a way I can use it without having to store an entire Django project around it in the repository? How can I test it locally inside of another project?

I'm kind of new at this, so I'm sorry. In the past, I've used Buildout to build my projects, but I don't know if I could use the Buildout Django recipe without an enclosing project.

Is there a guide for doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django: how to write a reusable app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493330/django-how-to-write-a-reusable-app)

Comment: Not a duplicate, it just has a similar title - the linked question deals with something more specific (I've edited the linked question so that it's title reflects the question better).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

James Bennett in DjangoCon 2008 talked about how to develop reusable django applications which are well de-coupled and can be dropped into different projects. You can watch the talk [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4). He explains some good practices to follow for doing so. You can also look into some popular existing external apps (some by James Bennett himself) or even django.contrib which are available with django.

Use setuptools/distutils to package your apps over the [cheezeshop](http://pypi.python.org/pypi). I think these can help you:
http://bruno.im/2010/may/05/packaging-django-reusable-app/
https://github.com/Natim/django-reusable-apps

Comment: Can you recommend a good way of testing these applications? Should I include a sample project in my source control for being able to boot into the Django shell with the application and testing things out? I want to be able to play with my module, and if I simply run Python and try to import my models, I get a ton of errors about how the project settings aren't defined. Should I include a Django project in my repo?

Comment: @TK I develop a small sample project for dealing with this. It is not so difficut to write a minimal project for testing.

Comment: Should I include that in the repository or keep it separate?

Comment: Its better to keep it. Will help users as an example and developers as a test project.